# How to match number of Aspose revisions with Word doc revisions

Tags: python, ms-word, aspose, aspose.words

When I open a Word document with revisions, I observe a certain number of revisions, for instance, 4 revisions (1 insertion and 3 formatting). However, when I utilize Aspose.Word in Python to extract the revisions from the document, I obtain a different count, in this case, 12 revisions (2 insertions and 10 formatting). How can I handle these revisions programmatically to ensure that I end up with the same 4 revisions as observed in the document?

```
doc = aw.Document(word_doc)
revisions_count = doc.revisions.count
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access revisions in the document using [Document.revisions](https://reference.aspose.com/words/python-net/aspose.words/document/revisions/) collection. But in MS Word revisions usually are grouped. So to access revisions in the same way as they are represented in MS Word, it is more convenient to use [RevisionGroup](https://reference.aspose.com/words/python-net/aspose.words/revisiongroup/). For example see the following code:

```py
doc = aw.Document("C:\\Temp\\in.docx")
for group in doc.revisions.groups:
    print(f"Revision author: {group.author};\r\nRevision type: {group.revision_type}\r\nRevision text: {group.text}")
    print("=============================")
```